# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl despite the dependencies are defined

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jax-ws, webservice-client

Despite that I have defined the related dependencies as I have added below, getting the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl` exception when my app makes a call to the web service.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.10</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.10</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

p.s. The servlet container is `Apache Tomcat 9.0.4`.

p.s. Java version: `9.0.1`.

Comment: Got this error when migrating a soap client code from JDK8 to JDK21. Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl. Error got was resolved with FastInfoset-1.2.18.jar
gmbal-4.0.1.jar
ha-api-3.1.12.jar
jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar
jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar
jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar
jakarta.jws-api-2.1.0.jar
jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar
jakarta.xml.soap-api-1.4.2.jar
jakarta.xml.ws-api-2.3.3.jarjaxb-impl-2.3.3.jar
jaxws-rt-2.3.3.jar
management-api-3.2.2.jarmimepull-1.9.13.jar
pfl-basic-4.1.0.jar
pfl-tf-4.1.0.jar policy-2.7.10.jar

Comment: Continuation to jars list saaj-impl-1.5.2.jar
stax2-api-4.1.jar
stax-ex-1.8.3.jar
streambuffer-1.5.9.jar
woodstox-core-5.1.0.jar

Answer (score 24):

The first part of the answer by @reta works for me. These are the relevant dependencies from my pom (Java 10):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It works until version com.sun.xml.ws:rt:2.3.5.  It didn't work with version >3.x.x

Answer (score 20):

Today in the era of Jakarta, I needed the following two dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

One thing I find quite weird is that the second dependency is not from Jakarta, I thought all of these implementations were migrated. It works, but I'd appreciate if someone could comment on that.

Comment: I agree. I am facing a problem with com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt on Android, because the lib is using Java API that is not available on Android. I was expecting "the era of Jakarta" to be platform agnostic.

Comment: Before 3.0.0, the jars were renamed to jakarta but they still contain javax packages inside which means they're compatible with the com.sun stuff

Answer (score 17):

It seems like you may need to include this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Or (haven't checked it yet but should work) you may need to change the scope to import for POM dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.10</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>import</scope> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: ty for this answer. PEOPLE! those 2 dependencies are different. One is `rt` and other is `jaxws-rt`. 
After adding this dependency, if you get a SOAPVersion exception, upgrade the version to latest. At the time of writing, latest version is `rt` is 2.3.1

Answer (score 3):

I've got the same problem upgrading to Java 11 from Java 8.

The problem was change of [behavior in ForkJoinPool](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8172726), which classloader is as of jdk9 system classloader, not the main thread classloader, it can produce hard to solve ClassNotFound exceptions.

It's better explained in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59444016/878015

Answer (score -1):

Seems like the class `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl` is not available in `jdk-9`

```
jshell> Class.forName("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl")
|  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException thrown: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl
|        at URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:466)
|        at DefaultLoaderDelegate$RemoteClassLoader.findClass (DefaultLoaderDelegate.java:66)
|        at ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:543)
|        at ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:476)
|        at Class.forName0 (Native Method)
|        at Class.forName (Class.java:292)
|        at (#1:1)
```

which is available in jdk-8, I wonder if you can use jdk-8 if possible might solve the issue.

Comment: downgrading to JDK8 is not a solution